# Android image effects?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, android-image

I want to develop android livewallpaper and add water drop or rain or any other kind of effects to the wallpaper image, how can I do so ?

Comment: This should help you - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Answer (score 1):

I would look into LiveWallpaper.onCreateEngine, as well as OpenGl for advanced image effects.